# remove some text after "." from string, excl ".'space'" and last full stop in sentence

Tags: c++, string, do-while

I want to remove 3 characters after a full stop (.) and would like to exclude the last full stop in my string as well as all full stops that end a sentence (defined as full stop + space (. )).

My code thus far removes all full stops + 3 chars:

```
string test = "I would .asdlike to.aed remove a.thell these inserts.";

  string target = ".";

  int found=-1;

  do{
    found = test.find(target,found+1);

    if(found!=-1){
      test=test.substr(0,found)+test.substr(found+4);
    }
  }

    while(found != -1);

  cout << test << endl;
```

Unfortunately, I keep on getting an error with the final full stop in a string and it removes 3 chars when a string includes more than one sentence separated by a full stop (identified as (. )).

Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string class has a useful erase function for you, which I demonstrate here:

```
std::string test = "I would .asdlike to.aed remove a.thell these inserts. And also keep.asd mult.weriple sentences.";

char target = '.';

std::string::iterator stringIter;
for(stringIter = test.begin(); stringIter != test.end(); stringIter++) {
    if (*stringIter == target && stringIter < test.end() - 3 && *(stringIter+1) != ' ') {
        test.erase(stringIter, stringIter+4);
    }
}

std::cout << test << std::endl;
```

Really simple and put together relatively quickly.

And the output is:

```
I would like to remove all these inserts. And also keep multiple sentences.
```

Comment: Thank you, @Miguel Mendes. I have never used string:: iterator before, and some light googling on the subject has just opened my eyes to the possible uses. Thank you, my dude!

Answer (score 0):

I'd do like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void solve(std::string &str, char target) {
    std::string s;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.size();) {
        if (str[i] == target) {
            if (i + 4 >= str.size() and str[i] == target) s.push_back(str[i]);
            i += 4;
        } else {
            s.push_back(str[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    str = s;
}

int main() {

    std::string test = "I would .asdlike to.aed remove a.thell these inserts.";
    solve(test, '.');

    std::cout << test << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Outut:

```
I would like to remove all these inserts.
```